# jsf params conservation

Tags: ajax, jsf, parameters

I tried to create a an link - image that changes the language of a page. But I encountered an issue, that the GET url params got lost after the ajax call, so not only the language changed, but also the content changed because of no params. The solution I found is to write down every single param that I use accross the whole website and try put it into the command link. But, I hope that this is not a neatest solution. Can you think of one?

```
<h:commandLink id="language" actionListener="#{userBean.changeLanguage}">
 <f:param name="itemId" value="#{param.itemId}" />
 <f:param name="categoryId" value="#{param.categoryId}" />
 <f:ajax render="@all" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Yes, my site is not a huge one, there are just two params, but I want to learn for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them properties of a `@ViewScoped` bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.itemId}")
    private Long itemId;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.categoryId}")
    private Long categoryId;

    // ...
}
```

And they'll be there as long as the view-to-view conversation lasts.